# File upload with Swagger 5.0.0-rcX and .Net-Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, file-upload, swagger, .net-core-3.0

I am using .NetCore 3 and Swagger 5.0.0-rc4. I am trying to upload file(image) using Swagger but it does not work because the apply method in the IOperationFilter or even Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger are missing some attributes. For instance NonBodyParameter and Consumes do not exit in Swagger 5.0

Do anyone use face the same problem or tried to solve it?

```
public class FileOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {

        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (operation.OperationId.ToLower() == "apivaluesuploadpost")
            {
                operation.Parameters.Clear();
                operation.Parameters.Add(new **NonBodyParameter**
                {
                    Name = "uploadedFile",
                    In = "formData",
                    Description = "Upload File",
                    Required = true,
                    Type = "file"
                });
                operation.**Consumes**.Add("multipart/form-data");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Please do not post images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Instead [edit] your question and add the code as properly formatted markdown

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly file upload does not work? What's the expected result and the actual result?

Comment: To make File-upload works in Swagger you must do some customization to your FileOperationFilter and configure it in the StartUp class but this customization can't be implemented in Swagger 5.0 because it seems that some attributes are removed from Swagger 5.0.
The result I get when I implement IFormFile in without customization is as follows: Fetch errorundefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json

Comment: For nonbody check https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1147 and for Consumes - use annotations https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1296

Comment: I am stuck on the same problem; the choose file dialog button has disappeared since upgrading. So no idea how to test and verify this is working correctly.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to solve this in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.1.5

Swagger recognizes automatically IFormFile as a `multipart/form-data` media type.

You just have to delete the filter class and remove the `[FromForm]` or `[FromBody]` attribute from your parameter in the controller.

`void Post([FromForm] IFileForm file)` <= old

`void Post(IFileForm file)` <= new

Comment: This works with version 6.5.0. If someone is wondering "where is the file upload input?", you have to click the "try it out" button to actually see the file input 

Answer (score 2):

AS for the missing Parameters Now these are changed to OpenApiParameter and OpenApiOperation.

```
public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (operation.OperationId == "MyOperation")
            {
                operation.Parameters.Clear();
                operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
                {
                    Name = "formFile",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Description = "Upload File",
                    Required = true,
                    Schema= new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type="file",
                        Format="binary"
                    }
                }); 
                var uploadFileMediaType = new OpenApiMediaType()
                {
                    Schema = new OpenApiSchema()
                    {
                        Type = "object",
                        Properties =
                    {
                        ["uploadedFile"] = new OpenApiSchema()
                        {
                            Description = "Upload File",
                            Type = "file",
                            Format = "binary"

                        }
                    },
                        Required = new HashSet<string>()
                    {
                        "uploadedFile"
                    }
                    }
                };
                operation.RequestBody = new OpenApiRequestBody
                {
                    Content =
                {
                    ["multipart/form-data"] = uploadFileMediaType
                }
                };


            }
        }
```

Comment: No clue where you got the "uploadedFile" parameter